# unable to see bubbles in bubble map of plotly/python

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, kaggle

I am working on Ramen Ratings dataset from kaggle

I want to see the spread of no of reviews/country using `scatter_geo` from `plotly`

my code:

```
country_count = df['Country'].value_counts()
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter_geo(country_count, locations = country_count.index, size = country_count)
fig.show()
```

gave me this:
[image: plotly image]

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete scatter is not visible because of the default setting for the `locatioinmode` parameter of the `scatter_geo` function. It can be changed to `country name` when the locations are country names. The modified code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import pycountry

df = pd.read_csv('ramen-ratings.csv')
country_count = df['Country'].value_counts()
country_count = country_count.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Country', 'Country':'Count'})
fig = px.scatter_geo(country_count, locations='Country', locationmode='country names', size='Count')
fig.show()
```

The graph obtained is as follows:
[image]

The complete documentation can be accessed here: https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter_geo.html